# Unable to find css of a element , while using sections in siteprism

Tags: capybara, site-prism

Code does not have any other error basic structure is shown ,stuck in using the basic feature of section under

```
class Station_Drawer < SitePrism::Section
  element :dropdown1,"dropdown css"
end

class Radio_nav < SitePrism::Section
 section :stations,Station_Drawer, "some css"
end

class Radio_Homepage < SitePrism::Page
 section :radio_nav,Radio_nav,"some css"
end

##____steps

When(/^I click on station dropdown\.$/) do
  @page.radio_nav.stations.dropdown1.click
end
```

**Error**

> Unable to find css "dropdown css" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)

Comment: That would imply the element isn't on the page -- Without the HTML and the actual selectors being used there's not much more we can say about it

Comment: You're either on the wrong page or the css selector is wrong.

Comment: Css is present ,checked and verified,can use to have_dropdowncss it says true

Comment: Do you have any debugging tool in your code? If you are using ruby I suggest binding.pry or byebug. My only hunch on this (there isn't enough information to go on more) is that there is a race condition, the css is not present when you try and click. The reason it would work on the `.to have_<element>` is that matcher uses the default capybara wait functionality.  Maybe try add `@page.radio_nav.stations.wait_for_dropdown1` before your line that clicks the element.